# Launching a map app from a mobile website

Tags: html, mobile, maps, protocols

I'm looking to allow a user to click on a postcode and launch their native map app.

All the solutions I have seen are vendor specific. Is there a "maps" protocol that when invoked will launch the native app?

Something like "maps://"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no standard convention, each mobile OS implements this differently. You will have to detect the device and update your links accordingly.

E.g. Let's say we wanted to find the postcode W1J 7NT

- **iOS:**

  URI: `http://maps.apple.com/?q=W1J7NT`

  see: [Apple URL Scheme Reference - Map links](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/Articles/MapLinks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007894-SW1)
- **Android:**

  URI: `geo:0,0?q=W1J7NT`

  see: [Intents List: Invoking Google Applications on Android Devices](https://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/g-app-intents.htmlhttps://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/g-app-intents.html)
- **Windows phone:**

  URI: `maps:W1J7NT`

  see: [Opening native map apps from the mobile browser](http://habaneroconsulting.com/Blog/Posts/Opening_native_map_apps_from_the_mobile_browser.aspx)
- **Blackberry:**

  URI: `javascript:blackberry.launch.newMap({'address':{'zipPostal':'W1J7NT'}});`

  see: [Opening native map apps from the mobile browser](http://habaneroconsulting.com/Blog/Posts/Opening_native_map_apps_from_the_mobile_browser.aspx)

You will also have to take into account the OS version as these URIs may have changed in earlier versions of each OS.

Comment: Alas, the Blackberry solution seems to work inside a WebWorks app only, not inside a traditional web app/web site delivered through HTTP.